# Positioning Logo in header using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position my logo at the top left, inside the navbar.

1. My logo will not respond when I try to position it to the far-left of the navbar using 'margin-right'.

   2. When I position the logo to the left, it is pushing the menu out to the right to the middle of the navbar.

Could anyone give me advice?

[image: Picture]

Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Arabella Hill</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href='#'><img src="img/arabella.png" class="img-responsive" img style="max-width:300px; margin-top:-80px; margin-right: 100px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-header">Admin & Dashboard</li>
          <li><a href="#">Admin 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Admin 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Comment: I have none, it is bootstrap.

Comment: If I have any, I have styled it in the HTML file.

Comment: I have added a picture, as you can see there is space between logo and the left size of the navbar. The menu also got pushed out to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "margin-left" with a negative value?

... margin-top:-80px; margin-left:-20px; ...

You may need to alter the value to suit the image dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some other styling on the .navbar or .navbar- header classes that's pushing it right.

Have a look on the the browser inspection tool to check these DIVs for extra styling.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the margin-right on your logo. That is pushing your nav to the right.

I would advise putting your styles in a CSS file but if you're going to do inline try something like this if you want it against the left side of the screen

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href='#'><img src="img/arabella.png" class="img-responsive" style="max-height:50px; margin-top:-80px; margin-left: -30px;"></a>
```

I would also advise using the developer inspector on your browser to see how padding and margin are affecting the logo.